# Leave a for loop containing async-await promises at once

Tags: javascript

I know if we have an async-await promise inside a for loop like this it will await for resolving the `Proceed` function on each of the iterations and after the last one we can see the log below the for loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i < guidePack.length; i++){ 
    await Proceed(guidePack[i]);
}
console.log('Guide is resolved!'); // we will see this only after all of the Proceeds are resolved
```

Now, what if we want to leave the for at once? like when a user presses the Enter key?

I came up with this code to do it and it seems to work fine:

```js
let guidePack = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

let ProceedResolved,
    ProceedRejected;




guide(); // initiate proccess

async function guide() {
      StartCaptureKeyPress();
  for(let i = 0; i < guidePack.length; i++){ 
      await Proceed(guidePack[i]);
  }
  console.log('Guide is resolved!');
}


// this function executes speaker function, at speaker function we will resolve the promise
function Proceed(e) {

  console.log(e); // log A and B and C  
  speaker();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    ProceedResolved = resolve; // resolve the Proceed when ProceedResolved() executes
    ProceedRejected = reject;
  });

}

function speaker() {
  // resolve proceed after 6 seconds
    setTimeout(() => ProceedResolved(), 3000);

}

// Capture 'Enter Key' press
function StartCaptureKeyPress() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDownCapture);
    function onKeyDownCapture (event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log('Enter Key Pressed');
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDownCapture);
        event.preventDefault();
        if (typeof ProceedRejected === "function") { ProceedRejected(); }
      }
    }
}
```

As you see the code works fine and rejecting one promise will bring us out of the for loop as expected.  but each time we reject the promises we get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) undefined

I think we get this error cause we didn't catch the reject error but I don't know :

- If this error cause any unexpected behavior in the rest of the code or execution of any part of the code?
- If I need to care about this and catch it?
- How to fix this error?

Comment: The error is because you call `reject` through `ProceedRejected()`. There is no argument there, so you get `undefined` as the reject reason. Also, I'm not sure this is the best way to go about it. I'd just have something like `if(shouldCancel) return;` in the loop and then just have some functionality that will enable or disable the condition. No need to modify the `Proceed` function - I don't see value in making it dependent on details such as these when you can simply avoid calling it.

Comment: I have 12000 lines of code and if I want to put `if(shouldCancel) return;` in each 3 - 4 lines it would be a nightmare for me :) So I can ignore the error?

Comment: I'm still not sure the solution is "make `Proceed` tightly coupled and add `StartCaptureKeyPress` in each loop". You can just extract the whole thing to a helper higher order function that takes an async function to loop over and a condition function that will terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fix this error as you suspected: by catching it:

```
async function guide() {
  try {
      StartCaptureKeyPress();
      for(let i = 0; i < guidePack.length; i++){ 
          await Proceed(guidePack[i]);
      }
  }
  catch(err) {
      // do whatever you want
  }
  console.log('Guide is resolved!');
}
```

Not catching the error will cause issues with any task resolving within the same event loop because the interpreter will simply stop processing further code on any uncaught error. It may or may not cause issues with future tasks - in my experience it does not. You don't need to do anything extra but you need to catch it.

Personally I'd want to know if any real error happened in my code. You can do that by rejecting with your own message and then test to see if it is an error or just a proceed rejection:

```
// Capture 'Enter Key' press
function StartCaptureKeyPress() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDownCapture);
    function onKeyDownCapture (event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log('Enter Key Pressed');
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDownCapture);
        event.preventDefault();
        if (typeof ProceedRejected === "function") {
            ProceedRejected("PROCEED_REJECTION"); // <---- NOTE THIS!
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then you check it like this:

```
async function guide() {
  try {
      StartCaptureKeyPress();
      for(let i = 0; i < guidePack.length; i++){ 
          await Proceed(guidePack[i]);
      }
  }
  catch(err) {
      if (err === "PROCEED_REJECTION") {
        // do nothing
      }
      else {
        console.error(err); // or pop up an error dialog
      }
  }
  console.log('Guide is resolved!');
}
```